# Having some issues with 2sxc version 9.x: unable to select App/Content layout

Tags: 2sxc

I have upgraded to v. 9.1.3 and I still have the same issue that I found with previous 9.x versions, so I'm still forced to use v.8.12 .

The problem is that I am unable to select the layout of any App/Content when I insert it to the page, after inserting I only see this button:

[image: after inserting, clicking on this button give errors]

and when I click on it , nothing happen , and two errors appear in the console:

[image: Errors in Chrome Console]

note1: the same error happen when I install 2sxc v.9.1.3 (or any older 9.x) on new and clean DNN v.9.1 website.

note2: the same error happen when I click on the layout button (the one with glasses icon) on previously installed app from the previous 8.12 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing 'localhost' to be 'xlocalhost' in the var:

```
var
  path = window.location.pathname,
  isDevMode = window.location.hostname === 'localhost',
  apiUrl;
```

in the file: `DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\dist\ng\ui.html`

For more info, see: [$2sxc is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292362/2sxc-is-not-defined/45314721#45314721)