# $2sxc is not defined

Tags: runtime-error, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

After adding Content module to a page, I just get a round blue icon with white glasses. Clicking on it produces an error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: $2sxc is not defined 1 ui.html:20:5
<anonymous> http://localhost/DotNetNuke/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/ng/ui.html:20:5
```

Clicking 'Change Template / Layout' in pencil menu also does nothing. This happened after upgrading from 2sxc 8.12 to 9.02.  I checked the file and of course could not see $2sxc defined anywhere. I have installed on other sites and not had this problem, but it is failing on my localhost installation. DNN 9.1.1  I have tried uninstalling 2sxc and deleting all the Tosic... files I can find, then reinstalling, but I get the same results.

Similar to: [Having some issues with 2sxc version 9.x: unable to select App/Content layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412446/having-some-issues-with-2sxc-version-9-x-unable-to-select-app-content-layout)

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a bug in that version, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this after a little debugging and following the code. The problem happens on localhost implementations. There is a file: `DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\dist\ng\ui.html`
that contains the code in a script container:

```
var
  path = window.location.pathname,
  isDevMode = window.location.hostname === 'localhost',
  apiUrl;
```

The problem is that it thinks it is in 'DevMode' when it is on localhost and therefore sets:

```
devPath = 'http://2sxc.dev/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/a4/';
```

which is certainly not a valid URL on my system, and apparently not on the web either. So the solution is to have it avoid 'DevMode' and everything works as it should. I did this by modifying the 'localhost' to be 'xlocalhost' and it worked like a charm. You could also just set it to false.